# Pcap capture merge problem

Tags: merge, capture, wireshark, pcap, tcpdump

I have two pcap files

```
$ capinfos cap1_stego0.pcap 
File name:           cap1_stego0.pcap
File type:           Wireshark/tcpdump/... - libpcap
File encapsulation:  Raw IP
Number of packets:   713
```

and

```
$ capinfos cap1_wlan0.pcap 
File name:           cap1_wlan0.pcap
File type:           Wireshark/tcpdump/... - libpcap
File encapsulation:  Ethernet
```

I want to merge them, but the incapsulation is different. If i use

```
mergecap -v -w asd.pcap cap1_stego0.pcap cap1_wlan0.pcap -T rawip
```

or

```
mergecap -v -w asd.pcap cap1_wlan0.pcap cap1_stego0.pcap -T rawip
```

Wireshark doesn't recognize the second past file and shows packets of `cap1_wlan0.pcap` or packets of `cap1_stego0.pcap` as `raw packet data` respectively. Also using "tcpslice" to remove ethernet layer of `cap1_wlan0.pcap` (to have both file with `rawip` encapsulation) show me unrecognized packet data.

How can i do? there is a way to merge pcap with different encapsulation or to convert eth->rawip or rawip->eth? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to convert a RAW_IP file to an ethernet encapsulated file (which can then be merged with other ethernet-encapsulated files):

1. Use tshark to get a hex dump of the packets from the RAW_IP file:

   ```
   tshark -nxr pcap-file-name | grep -vP "^ +\d" > foo.txt
   ```

   ( grep is used to remove the "summary" lines from the tshark output).
2. Use text2pcap to convert back to a pcap file while adding dummy
   ethernet headers:

   ```
   text2pacp -e 0x0800 foo.txt foo.pcap
   ```

If you want to keep the timestamps, you'll have to play around a bit with the tshark output
to get a text file which contains the timestamps in a format which text2pcap will accept and also contains the hex packet info.

[[
Does tcpslice have an option to remove ethernet headers ?
(Looking at the man page, it appears that tcpslice is used to extract time-ranges from a pcap file).

If you do have a way to remove ethernet headers from a capture file, you must make sure the resulting pcap file has an encapsulation type of RAW_IP before trying to read it with wireshark, mergecap , etc).

Also note that the -T switch to mergecap just forces the encapsulation type specified in the file; The actual encapsulation isn't altered (i.e., no bytes are added/changed/deleted).
]]

Answer (score 0):

For merge pcap files try alternative utility  - [tcpmerge](https://github.com/wkoroy/tcpmerge)
sample merge command:
./tcpmerge asd.pcap cap1_wlan0.pcap cap1_stego0.pcap  OUTFILEMERGED.pcap